# selenium search through google suggestions

Tags: python, string, selenium

i am trying to add google suggestions into a single text,i.e i'm passing "best way" google suggests "lose weight" so i search "lose weight" google suggests "in 30 days" so i search "30 days" and so on
`Final` is all suggestions added together ,however i'm getting repetitive results,`windowSize` is the number of words that should be run in search

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from random import randint
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36"')
options.add_argument('headless')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/timmy/Python/chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/ncr")
modifiedSearch="best way"
windowSize=2
z=1
Final=modifiedSearch
desiredInput=100
while len(Final)<desiredInput:
    temp3=modifiedSearch
    Search=driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    Search.clear()
    temp='"'+modifiedSearch+'"'
    Search.send_keys(temp)
    sleep(0.5)
    temp2='//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div[1]/div/span'
    try:
        modifiedSearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/div/span').text
        modifiedSearch = " ".join(modifiedSearch.split()[-windowSize:])
        if modifiedSearch.split()[windowSize-1]==temp3.split()[0]:
            print("xx")
            raise NoSuchElementException
    except NoSuchElementException:
        modifiedSearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(temp2).text
        modifiedSearch = " ".join(modifiedSearch.split()[-windowSize:])
        print("mod: %s" % modifiedSearch)



    print(modifiedSearch)
    Final=Final+" "+modifiedSearch.split()[0]

driver.close()
print (Final)
```

Output:

```
best way lose weight weight weight weight weight weight weight weight weight weight weight weight weight
```

the way it should go is like this

*best way* gives *to lose weight*

*lose weight* gives *in 30 days*

*30 days* gives *of night*

**Note**:please notice that i am searching the last two words of google suggestions

i need to avoid these repetitions somehow output should be`best way lose weight 30 days of night ...`

please notice that i am using the last two words(windowSize) in the "search suggestions",

*i hope this question is compliant with stack overflow terms.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected, but google is actually giving the same result! You can verify this by commenting out your line

```
#options.add_argument('headless')
```

Then just look at the search results popping up, and you will see that in fact Google is the one that is looping like this. You can perhaps try to grab a random result from the results list, or increase your window size (or maybe both) to try to give Google more to work with!

Comment: thank you for comment, but this definitely does not count as an answer

Comment: @timmyturner I disagree. You say your code does not work because it returns repetitive results. I am telling you that it does what you're asking it to, but ***Google*** is giving you repetitive results. I gave a couple suggestions to fix it such as increasing window size (which on my machine helps, but it still gets caught in a loop), picking an option at random instead of the same slot every time, or implementing logic to check if it is the same and if so: get the next item on the list instead. I'm not sure which solution is best for you, so I cannot be expected to provide an answer to match.